# Excel VBA BuiltInDocumentProperties with references

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, metadata, keyword

I´m currently building an excel userform, where you fill out textboxes in the form which then writes those inputs into excel sheet cells. After the form is being closed, that specific sheet is being saved as a pdf. Now since I don´t want to add the keywords in the metadata of the pdf after saving it, I have to add keywords to the excel file before the saving process, so that the pdf uses those same keywords. Until now, I gave those keywords with the code

```
ActiveWorkbook.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Keywords") = "example"
```

This worked pretty well. But it would be way easier and more automated, if I could fetch certain information, which is entered in the form, and use those as keywords. I have tried that with:

```
ActiveWorkbook.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Keywords") = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
```

but that does not work. Does anyone know if there is a mistake or another way to do it?

THANK YOU!

Comment: What does "that does not work" entail? Is nothing assigned? Is there an error message?

Comment: for the last couple of days, there was simply no keyword assigned to the pdf. now it works somehow. I have no Idea what I have done differently. But still thank you for your reply.